# Search a table for specific values in cell C and copy corresponding value in Cell A and Cell B over to a different table

Tags: google-sheets

Table 1:

```
name1,flight1,Y
name2,flight2,N
name3,flight3,Y
name4,flight4,N
name5,flight5,Y
```

Table 2:

```
name1,flight1
name3,flight3
name5,flight5
```

If value in cell C is Y then copy corresponding name and flight over to a different table.  continuously check all rows in table for a change to Y.

Any suggestions on what Sheets function I should be using?

Thanks,  Paul

Comment: thank you for your quick response however I'm having a hard time translating to my spreadsheet.  Lets try this: everything is in one worksheet.  The search table is from A4:F11, would like to search cells F4-F11 for a Y, if found then copy corresponding data in A4-A11 and B4-B11 into new table on same worksheet.  In this case copied values would go into A17-B21.  make sense?

Comment: can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: New to this site.  How do I upload a screenshot of my spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  I created everything like you have below and entered your formula in F2;  =INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D&E2:E, {A2:A&B2:B, C2:C}, 2, 0))) and getting blanks.  What am I doing wrong?  Is formula in wrong place?

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AT6tg1lAhietsfTsDdf-sVjNDiUldZ-yZnL-UNhHyNg/copy

Comment: Ok, I see what you did.  thanks for a copy of spreadsheet so I could see.  You entered in all values in both Blue and Red and then used your formula to find the Y value for each in red.  I actually want to search A2-C6 looking for Y and resulting in a copy of A2 and B2 over to D2 and E2, A4 and B4 over to D3 and E3 and then A6 and B6 over to D4 and E4.  Is that possible to do?

Comment: I see... answer and the sheet updated

Comment: That did it!!!  OMG, you just saved me so much time.  Plus I now know about the filter formula.  Thank you sir!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try on row 2 or edit ranges as you need:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, {Sheet2!A2:A&Sheet2!B2:B, Sheet2!C2:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=FILTER(A:C, C:C="Y")
```

Comment: having a hard time translating to my spreadsheet.  Lets try this: